# ASP.NET contact us page function issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a contact us page using C# but it doesn't work.
I've tried some versions of these functions before for register pages and update profile pages but here I can't why it doesn't read the data from the form. Can someone help me, please?
Here is the code:

```
    public partial class contact: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string email = "*****";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack)
            {
                string from = Request.Form["email"].ToString();
                string subject = Request.Form["subject"].ToString();
                string data = Request.Form["msg"].ToString();
                sendMsg(from, subject, data);
            }
        }

        protected void sendMsg(string from, string subject, string data)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.To.Add(email);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = data;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, "*****");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            Response.Write("Mail sent!");
        }
    }



<form action="contact.aspx">
     <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Your name: " name="name" id="name" required></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Email: " name="email" id="email" required></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Subject: " name="subject" id="subject" required></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Message: " name="msg" id="msg" required></p>
    <p><input class="w3-light-grey w3-padding-large" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Where's the markup? Show us where the form fields are defined and posted please.

Comment: Edited. tnx. I couldn't place too much code because it said to me "Too much code" or something like that...

Comment: form submit default is get. Your fields would be in the url, not the request.form. Put a method="post" in there and see if that helps. <form method="post">

Comment: It doesn't help, I've already tried it. same result...

Comment: shouldn't it be !this.IsPostBack

Comment: No, it doesn't, It should be IsPostBack because it waits until you submit the form.